# Partitions of unity with arbitrary Lip-constants

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, metric-embeddings, paracompactness, partition-of-unity

Lets make things simple. Suppose we have a compact metric space $(X,d)$ and then some Lipschitz partition of unity exists, say a collection $\mathcal{F}=\{f_n\}$ subordinate to some open cover $\mathcal{U}=\{U_n\}$.

Assume that the maximum Lipschitz constant in $\mathcal{F}$ is $L>0$.

Given $c>0$, can we alter $\mathcal{F}$ to some partition of unity $\mathcal{F}'$ which is still subordinate to $\mathcal{U}=\{U_n\}$ but has Lipschitz constant $\frac{L}{c}$?

However, I don't feel that this can be done for arbitrarily small $c$.

Thank you for any idea!

Comment: It is natural to assume that for some point $x$ there exists a unique $m$ such that $x\in U_m$ (otherwise some $U_n$ may dropped from the cover). But then any partition of unity subordinate to $\{U_n\}$ (meaning $\text{supp}\phi_n\subset U_n$ for all $n$) must have a function $\phi_m$ with $\phi_m(x)=1$, which implies its   Lipschitz constant must be at least $1/\text{dist}(x, \partial U_m)$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $X = [-1,1]$ consider the open sets
$$
U_1 = [-1,\epsilon], \quad U_2 = (-\epsilon,1]
$$
with a subordinate partition of unity
$$
\phi_1 : [-1,1] \to [0,1], \quad \phi_2 : [-1,1] \to [0,1]
$$
Then $\phi_1(-\epsilon) = 1$ and $\phi_1(\epsilon) = 0$, which forces the Lipschitz constant to be $1/(2\epsilon)$.

Depending on what exactly "subordinate" means for you, you can always replace $\phi_1$ by $N$ copies of $\phi_1/N$. That way, the Lipschitz constant will be as small as you want at the cost of having multiple partition of unity functions associated with one member of the cover.